# Working with Arrays / GetWebVirtualDirectory in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am new to PowerShell, so I got this far

```
$sites = Get-Website
$OrderSite = $sites | Where Name -eq 'SiteName'
$directories = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $OrderSite.Name
```

So that `$directories` looks like

```
Name             Physical Path
----             -------------
Profile          C:\Path1
WebMain          C:\Path1
```

Now I am stuck

```
$directories[0] = 

Name             Physical Path
----             -------------
Profile          C:\Path1
```

But `$directories[0].Name`, `$directories[0]["Name"]`, `$directories |Where Name -eq 'Profile'`, `$directories |Where Name -like 'P*'` and `$directories | ForEach {$_.Name }` are all null

However, `$directories | ForEach {$_ }` and `$directories |Where Name -like '*'`

Return the full list.

So what is the correct way to filter or Access the property Name or how do I verify what the names or properties of my array real are?

Comment: What does `$directories.GetType()` or `$directories | Get-Member` return?

Comment: `$directories | select name`

Comment: `GetType()` returns Object[]  BaseType of System.Array, `Get-Member` returns TypeName: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#application#virtualDirectory

Comment: So I guess the correct way is `$directories[0].path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't test this as no `IIS Provider` on my PC.

I believe this will get you what you're after, based on what works and doesn't work in the question:

```
$directories | Where-Object {Path -eq 'Profile'}
```

`Where-Object` expects a statement `{...}`

Comment: That also returns null the name of the field appears to be path even though the Column header says Name  also `Where path -eq ` .. also the path starts with a `\` that is not shown in the Name column... So change it to path and I will mark the answer since your comment lead me in the correct direction

Comment: @Mike huh, OK. Edit - saw your comment now, glad to hear it's sorted! You could post your answer and accept it, in case someone else has the same issue :-)